# How to find the source of the text for wordpress website? I want to change that text

Tags: functions

I have following code, which is generating the the text on the website. code resides in front-page.php file in the theme folder.

```
<p class="excerpt">
                <?php
                      $theExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                      $tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
                      $theExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", $theExcerpt);
                      echo $theExcerpt;
                      ?>
                </p>
```

Let me know if you want more information. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does it output anything ?

Comment: Hi, @AbdulAwal. Thank you for your reply. Yeah it does generate some text like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..." upto 8 words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is going into the page's Edit mode, by pressing "Edit" on that page, and then checking whether that text is by any chance the actual excerpt. If you can't see an "excerpt" section on that page you can go to the top of that page, click "Screen Options" on the top right, and tick the option "Excerpt" (see image). 
If you find that the excerpt of the page is actually empty, meaning that your theme is probably generating a predefined excerpt when no excerpt is present, you can download your theme to your pc and do an in-file search using the text it is generating (in your case "Lorem ipsum ..."). This way you can find out where it is in your theme's code that the text has been hard-coded.
You can use some software like AstroGrep in order to perform the search. 
[image]

Comment: Hi @Bob, thank you for your response to my question. But do you know any other way how i can find that place if i didn't got it through in-file search ?

Comment: Hey @IshanPatel, if the in-file search doesn't give you any results, it means that it probably isn't your theme that's directly generating the text. There are some themes that create their own plugins (the Avada theme is an example). In that case, you could also try looking into those plugins, or other plugins possible connected with the excerpt.

Comment: You can also try searching for part of the string (e.g. only "Lorem"), as in some cases the text will be divided between tags and searching for the whole string will not give you any results.

Comment: Hi @Bob, the interesting thing i found that the text which i wanted to place was already in the excerpt section on the same page. But what could be the reason that text is not appearing on the staging site? Do i have to make any change to the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code only output the_excerpt without the p tags, excerpt is part of the written post but can also be automatically generated, theme can have the support of excerpt and then the ox is viewable.

There's filters to change the excerpt lengh and other behaviour, you can learn more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) (read the example).

Note that there's also the filter wpautop to disable p tags in a function.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your reply @Benoti. But it didn't explain me the way to find that location or how to put some string in that div.

Comment: As I told you in my answer, this text in the_excerpt is part of the post, you must edit the related post and remove or edit the Lorem ipsum text. Don't forget that you can display the excerpt metabox with the option screen (if your theme as excerpt support). If you don't see anything in the edit post page, you'll need to look in the functions.php file (or another include files) of the parent theme and investigate for any custom function that will always put this text. Without any idea of which theme you use it's hard to help you to find this function.

Comment: Hi @Benoti, the interesting thing i found that the text which i wanted to place was already in the excerpt section on the same page. But what could be the reason that text is not appearing on the staging site? Do i have to make any change to the code ? Also i have come across the Lorem text in the file called ajax-actions.php file.

Comment: The theme you are using doesn't display it, ajax-actions.php does.. you'll find how to intergrate the excerpt un thé wp default theme.